# Pass Java array as an input for ELKI DBSCAN

Tags: cluster-analysis, data-mining, dbscan, elki

I have been able to use ELKI for DBSCAN using Java code and its amazingly fast compared to any other tool.
Till now I was working with a CSV file and using following to give that as an input.

```
params.addParameter(FileBasedDatabaseConnection.Parameterizer.INPUT_ID,fileLocation)
```

I am wondering how can I pass an array of (lat,long,timestamp) as an input instead of a CSV file. I am not able to figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good morning.

This is what the class `ArrayAdapterDatabaseConnection` is for.

```
DatabaseConnection dbc = new ArrayAdapterDatabaseConnection(...);

// Pass an instance, not a class, as parameter.
params.addParameter(
    AbstractDatabase.Parameterizer.DATABASE_CONNECTION_ID, dbc);
```

Alternatively, you can implement your own `DatabaseConnection` or `Parser`.

When woring with latitude, longitude, timestamp be careful with distances and types. Do not use Euclidean distance on lat,long,timestamp; instead carefully construct a domain specific similarity measure.

Comment: Thanks!! Its working. One prob regarding lables. "DatabaseConnection dbc = new ArrayAdapterDatabaseConnection(datamatrix,timestmp);" where timestmp I was using as labels. "labels = db.getRelation(TypeUtil.LABELLIST);" is giving me an error "No data type found satisfying: LabelList"

Comment: The labels are currently added as `TypeUtil.STRING` to the data. For `TypeUtil.LABELLIST` they would need to go through extra encapsulation. But the class probably should be changed that way for consistency.